# Flutter google map maker ontap

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

I'm pretty new in Flutter. It is amazing. I'm working on small app usign google maps. I have 6 points (Markers) and need to recognize which one was selected.
I've added ontap event into every marker with i-index (i = 0..5). When I tap/click on marker I always get 6. It should be 0..5 based on marker.

Thanx a lot, Gabriel

```
i=0;
marker.clear();
for (myPoint mar in globals.historia.items) {
  print(i.toString());
  marker.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(i.toString()),
    position: mar.pos,
    draggable: false,
    consumeTapEvents: true,
    onTap: () {
      print("Marker_id-${i.toString()}");
    },
  ));
  i++;
}
```

GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: myposition,
          zoom: 17.0,
        ),
        polylines: road, 
        markers: Set.of(marker),
      )

Answer (score 0):

When `onTap()` is triggered it calls `i` with its last value that's `== 6`, that's why every time you tap on a marker, the print method prints 6.
`i` is a global variable, that has its own address, so the `print` method will search for the value on that address every time `onTap` is called.

**I propose this solution** - replace youtr print method inside onTap with this : `print("Marker_id-${globals.historia.items.indexOf(mar)}")`

`mar` is a local variable inside the `for in` loop, and its value has never changed, so he will point on the same value, `onTap` will behave as you want.